# git rm -r doesn't work in a submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-rm

Try to change submodule as described in [git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)

```
$ git rm -r vendor/html-minifier
$ git submodule add https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier.git vendor/html-minifier
```

But it fails with following

```
rm 'vendor/html-minifier'
fatal: git rm: 'vendor/html-minifier': Is a directory
```

Comment: try git rm -rf vendor/html-minifier

Comment: Didn't help. The same as `git rm -r vendor/html-minifier`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://txt.binnyva.com/2008/07/remove-a-folder-from-git/

```
git rm -r vendor/html-minifier/.
```

Or maybe (from https://serverfault.com/questions/256421/cant-git-rm-a-directory)

```
git rm --cached -r dirname
```

Comment: try `git rm -r vendor/html-minifier/`. result:
`fatal: pathspec 'vendor/html-minifier/' did not match any files`

Comment: try: `git rm --cached -r dirname`, source: [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/256421/cant-git-rm-a-directory)

Comment: Thanks it works. It doesn't remove the actual content of folder, but it can be done with `rm`

Comment: your welcome, just accept a answer to tell that your problem is solved ^^